# Permutation statistics in multiple rows

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, eulerian-numbers

Usually we study the statistics of a permutation written in one row. Is there any result for the statistics of a permutation written in multiple rows? Let me give an example in order to be more clear: Let's put $1, 2, \cdots, 8$ into a $4\times2$ table and count the number of descents. Descents are defined to be a relationship that one number is greater than a number in the next column. If a number is greater than both of the numbers in the next column, we count twice. For example,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 3 & 6 & 8
\end{pmatrix}$$
has descent number $3$, because $2>1, 4>1, 4>3$. For putting $2N$ numbers into two rows, I computed that the difference between the numbers of permutations with even descents and odd descents are: $2, 8, 144, 3200, 152320, 8672256, \cdots$, but I cannot figure out what this series is, and especially, what its exponential generating function is.

If there is only one row, I know the result is given by the Eulerian numbers and Eulerian polynimials. Are there generalized results for multiple rows?

Comment: Please say what "even/odd" descents are defined to be.

Comment: As far as I know, the notion of descent is also sought in standard Young tableaux, but this is quite different from what you are are looking at.

Comment: Could you explain the numbers you calculated?  For $N = 2$ I count 16 permutations with an even number of descents and 8 with an odd number, for a difference of 8.  If I'm understanding the question correctly, this number has to be a multiple of $2^N$ for all $N$, because switching the two numbers in any given column doesn't affect the number of descents.  But 18, 4760, and 135504 aren't divisible by $2^2$, $2^4$, and $2^5$ respectively.

Comment: @coffeemath A permutation is said to have even descents if it has an even number of descents.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, they are quite different.

Comment: @RaviFernando You are absolutely correct. When I did the counting I ignored the order in a column. Let me correct them.

Comment: Oh I see now!  I didn't realize you were starting at $N = 2$ before.  (And actually shouldn't it be 2 for $N = 1$, or 1 without double-counting?  Not that it matters much, since it isn't on OEIS either way.)

Comment: @RaviFernando You are again correct. Sorry for being that careless. I ignored the double counting because this problem comes from a physics problem, where the order in the column doesn’t matter. I checked OEIS too. This can be a new item if we can figure out how it can be generated easily. It can be further generalized to some tableaux where the columns have arbitrary and different lengths, which are again of interest in physics. I feel I don’t have enough tools to deal with them. Therefore I am curious whether any people in math would be interested in this sort of problem.